# 1N4148W-7-F Diodes

Tags: diodes

I'm building a DIY keyboard. All the build logs I've seen use these diodes:

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/diodes-incorporated/1N4148W-7-F/1N4148W-FDICT-ND/815280

I'm trying to source the diodes locally, and have found these:

https://www.reichelt.de/schalt-diode-100-v-150-ma-sod-123-1n-4148w7f-dii-p219381.html?&trstct=pos_2

I can solder, but I need a little help. I am a little worried, as the part number differs slightly, and I'm unsure of the 150mA vs 300mA (is that the forward current?)

With these be fine in a low power project like a diy keyboard build (running a teensy 2)

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference between the diode types for your purposes. They're just cheap but very, very good common switching diodes.

Current rating, switching speed, voltage rating, leakage and so on are far more than enough in every case.